# Determination of the state-transition matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, computational-mathematics

I am trying to find the [state-transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) (STM) via different techniques $X'= AX$ where $A$ is time-invariant.
where $\phi$ is the STM.
$$\phi '=A \phi$$
Once we take the derivative of  $\phi '=A \phi$  we obtain $$\phi'' = \text{A}*\phi'..... (1)$$ or
$$ \phi''=A*A  \phi.... (2) $$

Note $\text A$ is a constant matrix.

So the question is can I numerically integrate equation (1) or (2) with initial conditions on $\phi(0)$ and $\phi'(0)$ and obtain STM?

I tried it using Mathematica but answers do not match. Thanks
[Code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE2dd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Given ${\bf A} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, the state-transition matrix satisfies the following matrix differential equation

$$ \dot {\bf X} (t) = {\bf A} {\bf X} (t) $$

whose solution is ${\bf X} (t) = \exp( t {\bf A} ) \, {\bf X} (0)$.